# Redirect 301 example.org to example.com and subpages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to make a 301 redirection from `example.org` to `example.com`

The issue that I face is that all the pages are in the form of `example.org/page-something.html` and I want to redirect to `example.com/page-something`.

I can't figure it out no matter the tries in `.htaccess`.

My current code is like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\.html https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first site is a static website and the second one is WordPress in case it matters.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible things wrong.

First you have to make sure that `.htaccess` is available and enabled on your `example.org` site.  Put some nonsense into the file temporarily and verify that the server throws a 500 Internal Server error.  If you find that `.htaccess` isn't being used:

- Check that the server is Apache (as opposed to Nginx or IIS which don't use `.htaccess` files.)
- Check that the Apache server configuration has `AllowOverride all` which is what enables `.htaccess`.

Your rewrite has a potential problem in it.  From within `.htaccess` the path this is matched does not start with a slash.  This is different than rewrite rules used in the main Apache configuration files where the path does start with a slash. To fix this you can make the starting slash optional with a `?`.  Then the rule should work in either location:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You could also experiment with using a [mod_alias RedirectMatch rule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead:

```bash
RedirectMatch "^/?(.*)\.html" "https://example.com/$1"
```

Comment: Unlike `RewriteRule`, `RedirectMatch` always matches against a root-relative URL-path starting with a slash, so no need to make it optional. However, your `RedirectMatch` is a default 302, not a 301. (I would also be inclined to use an end-of-string anchor to avoid matching `/foo.htmlnonsense`.)

Comment: @MrWhite Making the slash optional in the `RedirectMatch` allows the target to have a slash before the `$1`.  If you don't make it optional, you have to append the `$1` directly to the domain name.  That will work, but it makes it look like you are modifying the domain name.

Comment: Most sites don't have URLs like `/foo.htmlnonsense`.  If they do, they are usually error URLs where the nonsense should be removed. Adding the end-of-string anchor would make the rule ignore such URLs rather than redirecting after removing the nonsense.

Comment: But the slash doesn't need to be _optional_, it just needs to be outside the capturing group (which is what you have).